# Use bash ´ls´ command in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook

I just want to type the same bash command in jupyter which I also use in the bash terminal.

I find the content of a folder in bash using this command and get the following output:

`>>> ls data/bulldozers/
     Train.csv`

However when I use the same command in a jupyter notebook:

```
>>> PATH = "data/bulldozers/"
    !ls {PATH}

    ls: data/bulldozers/: No such file or directory
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: That there is "No such file or directory", at least at that relative path to your current working directory. Check your working directory, i.e. `pwd` and then just `ls` to see what's in there. Make sure you have permissions

Comment: Try `!pwd` to see what directory you are in the notebook.

Comment: I assumed `ls` would begin search in my Users/philipp/ folder by default? Is that not so?

Comment: @Philipp the path is relative to whatever folder you launched the notebook.

Comment: @pault thanks for the answer. How do I get to folders outside of the working directory then?

Comment: Use absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

What solved the issue was to place the folder with the file I needed to find in the directory of my notebook.